# How to add together the total of 2 random numbers between 1 and 6 5 times

Tags: python, random, numbers

I'm making a code in python where two dice are rolled 5 times and the total of those 5 separate rolls are added together- however after generating the numbers i don't know how to add them together.

```
def roll(value):
    for i in range(5):
        import random
        roll1 = float(random.randint(1,7)) 
        roll2 = float(random.randint(1,7))
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: BTW why do you convert integers to floats here? A sum of integers is also an integer. Also, you don't need  to `import random` in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
from random import randint

def roll():
    rollSum1 = 0 
    rollSum2 = 0 
    for i in range(5):
        rollSum1 += float(randint(1,7))
        rollSum2 += float(randint(1,7))
    return rollSum1, rollSum2
```

if you want to return de sum of the two rollSum just change the line:

```
    return rollSum1, rollSum2
```

and write

```
    return rollSum1 + rollSum2
```